# QPixmap corrupt image

Tags: python, pyside

Why is my image corrupt when displayed using simple QPixMap and draw commands. Every once in awhile it will display correctly.

```
self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(128,128)
painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._pixmap)
brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor(240, 20, 20, 255))
painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(brush, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine,QtCore.Qt.SquareCap))
painter.drawLine(0, 0, self._pixmap.width(), self._pixmap.height())
painter.drawLine(self._pixmap.width(), 0, 0, self._pixmap.height())
painter.end()
```

[image]

Comment: That is the content of your memory. What image you get is undefined behaviour. declaration != initialization. You are only declaring. `QPixmap.fill(color)` initializes your `QPixmap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `fill` before painting using `QPainter`, look at reference [here](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPixmap.html#PySide.QtGui.QPixmap) about QPixmap constructor

> This will create a PySide.QtGui.QPixmap with uninitialized data. Call PySide.QtGui.QPixmap.fill() to fill the pixmap with an appropriate color before drawing onto it with PySide.QtGui.QPainter .